# How to set HGrow property dynamically?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I'm trying to make my TextFill resize automatically inside HBox. To do that using sceneBuild or fxml code it's quite simple just setting the HGrow property to alway like in picture bellow:

[image]

But for some reasons I have to generate my components dynamically by java code and this way I can't find how to set this property to my textField.

```
HBox hBox = new HBox();
TextField autoCompleteNome = new AutoCompleteTextField();
TextField autoCompleteCargo = new AutoCompleteTextField();
Button btnRemove = new Button("Excluir");

hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
hBox.setFillHeight(true);
hBox.setMinHeight(39);
hBox.setSpacing(5);

autoCompleteName.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
autoCompleteName.autosize();
autoCompleteName.setMinHeight(30);
autoCompleteName.setPrefHeight(30);
autoCompleteName.setItems(data);
autoCompleteName.setPromptText("Nome");

hBox.getChildren().add(autoCompleteName);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the growth priority of a HBox child node using the static [HBox.setHgrow(node, priority)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#setHgrow%28javafx.scene.Node,%20javafx.scene.layout.Priority%29) function.

There is a sample in the [HBox javadoc class description](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html).

"For example, if an hbox needs the TextField to be allocated all extra space:"

```
 HBox hbox = new HBox();
 TextField field = new TextField();
 HBox.setHgrow(field, Priority.ALWAYS);
 hbox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Search:"), field, new Button("Go"));
```